# My C# array only sums and averages the last user input

Tags: c#, arrays

I built a C# program in which the user is prompted to enter 10 different values and then the program is supposed to sum and average these values and print the sum and average.  The problem I am having is that my program is only capturing the last value entered...please help!

```
namespace ConsoleApplication4
{
    class Program
    {
        const int count = 10;

        static void Input(double[] numbers, int num)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter integer {0}: ", i + 1);
                numbers[num] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }

        static void Average(double[] numbers, int num)
        {
            double sum = 0;
            double avg = 0;
            for (int i =    0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
            {
                sum += numbers[i];
            }
            avg = sum / numbers.Length;

            Console.WriteLine("The sum of the inputs is {0} and the average is {1}", sum, avg);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double[] numbers = new double[count];
            for (int num = 0; num < 1; num++)
            {
                Input(numbers, num);
                Average(numbers, num);
                Console.WriteLine("Press the Enter Key");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Joe, it is a good time to learn how to debug your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    Console.Write("Enter integer {0}: ", i + 1);
    numbers[num] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

That should be

```
numbers[i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Thank you guys!  I am a noob at this and it took me awhile just to get to this point.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

In you Input method, you're assigning user input to numbers[num] instead of numbers[i].

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your `Input()` method, you're always storing in the `num` index in your for loop, but `num` doesn't change in the loop. You should be using `numbers[i]` instead of `numbers[num]`.